# Which tag should I use for the choice of the text language on a website if I want to be able to customize it freely with CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, multiple-choice

Below are two HTML snippets to let the user choose a language for the page:

1. one uses `<select>` and `<option>`s,
2. the other uses a `<div>` and alternated `<input>`/`<label>`s.

What I plan to do is pick one of those (or a better one, if one exists) and use CSS to customize the appearance of it such that something like ***the following would appear at the top right of the page, i.e. all alternatives should be show at the same time all the time on the page***.¹

[image]

I any of 1 and 2 which is to be objectively preferred over the other?

Are there any pro and cons of 1 vs 2?

```html
<select name="language" id="language" value="ENG">
  <option>ITA</option>
  <option selected="selected">ENG</option>
  <option>FRE</option>
</select>
```

```html
<div class="language">
  <input type="radio" id="italian" name="fav_language" value="ita">
  <label for="italian">Italiano</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="english" name="fav_language" value="eng" checked="checked">
  <label for="english">English</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="french" name="fav_language" value="fre">
  <label for="french">Français</label><br>
<div>
```

---

¹ I've obtained this static image via a `<ul>` with 3 `<svg>`s inside a corresponding `<li>`, so I haven't bothered adding something like an external shadow to mark the selected language, but I'd do it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to freely style your language selector by means of showing all options at the same time through flag images I think none of the above options are the best choice. There's no need to get complicated. Try a `div` and `a` links solution to better fit your goal.

Something like `</div><ul class="languages"><li class="nav-item"><a href="#english">English /a></li><li class="nav-item"><a href="#french">french</a></li></ul>`

Comment: Does using `select` and `option` in the HTML prevent me from obtaining the result in the figure via CSS?

Comment: I don't understand your point. What do you mean by "prevent me from obtaining the result in the figure via CSS"? You can use `CSS` to style almost anything within `html` markup, `select` and `option` are not an exception as long as I know.

Comment: The image in my question clearly shows and tells you that I want to show **both/all** the options all the time at the top right of the page. I'll make it even clearer. Does the `select`+`option` approach allow showing all options all the time?

Comment: You mean to show a clickable image for each language option? If it's what you want to achieve, and sorry for not understanding that from the beginning, I think you can't do that if you use `select`. But it would be also difficult to use inputs and would need to style very hard to be shown as you want. Why not using `div ` and `a` links instead?

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that. I start to think that to have full freedom, one has to rely fully on CSS and use only simple stuff in HTML.

Comment: Something like this `</div>
    <ul class="nav no-search">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#one">One</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    </ul>`

Comment: Yeah! There's no need to get complicated when you can obtain the same or better results using simple `html` and `css`. I will update the answer to let it clear according to your question.

Comment: Would you consider, if my answer really was useful to you, to select it as the accepted one?

Comment: Your answer is partly useful, but I feel, as it is now, it's essentially just food for thoughts. Which is good, sure, but it's far from being an answer, imho.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion. Anyway you are in better position than before. Don't worry, I am not here looking for reputation but just trying to help people who are in trouble as I been before or as I am right now. I am glad of being able to help you somehow.